# Visibility Clash between Drop Down Menus and PageTransitions

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

I have two capabilities that seem to be clashing. Each works perfectly when I remove the other. The first capability is a row of drop down menus. Right below that I am implementing the [PageTransitions](https://github.com/codrops/PageTransitions) library. My problem is that my drop down menus no longer appear when this is present. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

When I comment out the transitions library, the drop downs function perfectly. When I substitute in a regular old `<div>` and give it a background color, I can see the drop downs. I've looked through the library, and have identified where the z-index values appear. The highest z-index value in the library is 999999, so I gave my drop-downs a z-index of 1000000. Still nothing.

The div that is blocking the drop down is described in this css [file](https://github.com/codrops/PageTransitions/blob/master/css/component.css) in the classes `pt-page` (line 12), `pt-page-1` (line 76) and `pt-page-current` (line 31). I tried taking out any references to backface visibility, but that changed nothing. These are the exerpted classes from this file:

```
.pt-page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.pt-page-current,
.no-js .pt-page {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is the relevant code from my html file:

```
    <div id="innerframe">
        <div id="dropdown">
        <ul class="navigation">

            <li><a href="#">Workout Builder</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Send Email</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Building Blocks</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                </ul>           
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Other Capabilities</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>

        </ul> <!--navigation-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div> <!--dropdown-->

        <div class="pt-triggers">
            <button id="iterateEffects" class="pt-touch-button">Show next page transition</button>
            <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
            </div>
    <!-- /dl-menu-wrapper-->
    </div><!-- /triggers -->

        <div id="pt-main" class="pt-perspective">
            <div class="pt-page pt-page-1"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions</h1></div>
            <div class="pt-page pt-page-2"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions</h1></div>
            <div class="pt-page pt-page-3"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions</h1></div>
            <div class="pt-page pt-page-4"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions</h1></div>
            <div class="pt-page pt-page-5"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions</h1></div>
            <div class="pt-page pt-page-6"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions</h1></div>
        </div>

    </div> <!--innerframe-->
```

And the css for the navigation class:

```
/* Adjusting the margins, paddings and no list styles */
.navigation  {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    list-style:none;
    height:36px;
    z-index:1000000;
}   

/* Little tricking with positions */
.navigation  li {
    float:left;         /* Show list items inline */
    width:200px; 
    position:relative; 
}

/* Playing with Main Categories */
.navigation  li a {
    background:#262626; 
    color:#aaaaaa;
    display:block;      /* Making sure a element covers whole li area */
    padding:8px 7px 8px 7px; 
    text-decoration:none; /* No underline */
    border-top:1px solid #73bf00;
    text-align:center; 
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.navigation  li a:hover {
    color:#73bf00;
}

/* Sub Cat Menu stuff*/
.navigation  ul {
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    display:none; /* Hide it by default */
    margin:0 0 0 -1px; 
    padding:0; 
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:3px solid #73bf00;
}

.navigation  ul li {
    width:200px; 
    float:left; 
    border-top:none;
}

/* Sub Cat menu link properties */
.navigation  ul a {
    display:block;      /* Making sure a element covers whole li area */
    height:15px;
    padding:8px 7px 13px 7px; 
    color:#aaaaaa;
    text-decoration:none;   
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:1px dashed #000000;
}

.navigation  ul a:hover {
    color:#73bf00;
}
```

Sorry for all the code. I can't figure which lines are causing the problem. Thanks to anyone who might take a look at this. I really appreciate it. I don't know where else to turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dropdowns are hidden behind the main content div, specifying the `z-index` could bring them to the top.

Keep in mind that the in order to use `z-index` on an element, you also need to set the positioning to something like `position: relative`.

Try adding `position: relative` to your `.navigation` class.

Comment: That was it. All I had to to was add `position:relative`. Thanks a lot!